# Show DropDown based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a basic `Drop down list` for operators. 
I was thinking is there  a way to show dropdown item based on selection. If in `Category` Drop Down i select Price which is integer than operator dropdown should show only integer related items.

Thanks

Comment: And your back again to help me ;)

Comment: yes if I can :) btw the link you provided is pointing to "Filter Builder"

Comment: you means to says if we have select string type item form drop down then only string type related items.. is it right ??

Comment: @DhavalJaviya Yes totally right :). If string then string related items, if int then int related items.

Comment: @Richa i thing you want to develop filter like when you select price then filter based on the "price" if user select "Payroll Deduction" filter based on the "Payroll Deduction" ??

Comment: @DhavalJaviya Yes correct.

Comment: so we can pass that value to the Linq query or Sql query then it will resolve your problem. like i have select value from drop down price then i will pass the value "Price" to my query.

Comment: Any demo or sample code will be very usefull:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51318/discussion-between-richa-and-dhaval-javiya)

Comment: @Neel where are you sir ?? :)

Comment: here only looking at your problem :) btw no need of sir :P @Richa

Comment: Ooppss sorry ;) Will call u only @Neel:)

Comment: @DhavalJaviya Chat does not seem to work.:(

Comment: @DhavalJaviya how do i create a chat box again??

Comment: chat box again?? not getting you..

Comment: wanna take check box in mvc?? is it right ??

Comment: You are searching for some kind for event listener on `dropdown` and reload data in some kind of table? Am I right?

Comment: @szpic Kind of. When the item in first dropdown is suppose string, then show only string related option in second dropdown

Comment: What have you tried? What code do you have? Do you intend to get the whole stuff done? And yes, this question is asked, I dont know, so many times. Try reading the basics of JS... Google, dont be lazy!

Comment: @pjp It might have been asked many times but nothing what i am looking for.

Comment: What you need is to read about `events` and `DOM Manipulation` basics in JavaScript and without a single bit of code, no one is  gonna help you.

Comment: @pjp I had posted code and still no one helped :(

Comment: when? where? do I see that code here? No!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51324/discussion-between-pjp-and-richa)

Comment: sorry @Richa I was bit busy today and coudnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/22/

Javscript:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.category', function () {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.operator option').hide();
        $('.operator option.'+val).show();
       $('.operator option.'+val+':first').attr('selected','selected').change();
    });
});`

HTML:

```
<select class="category">
    <option val="price">Price</option>
    <option val="weight">weight</option>
    <option val="size">Size</option>
    <option val="dimension">Dimension</option>
</select>
<select class="operator">
    <option val="1" class="price">For Price 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="price">For Price 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="price">For Price 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="price">For Price 4</option>    
    <option val="1" class="weight">For Weight 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="weight">For Weight 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="weight">For Weight 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="weight">For Weight 4</option>    
    <option val="1" class="size">For Size 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="size">For Size 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="size">For Size 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="size">For Size 4</option>
    <option val="1" class="dimension">For Dimension 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="dimension">For Dimension 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="dimension">For Dimension 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="dimension">For Dimension 4</option>
</select>
```

you can modify it to change the type detection. I used class for selecting the option, you can set custom attributes in option in order to differentiate them. Hope it helps.