# Show dropdown value based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Is it possible for me to only display the related data on my second dropdown option when I click it on my first dropdown? I saw a similar question on stackoverflow, but I can't get it to work. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23264490/16729249) is available here. It works when I copy and paste the code from the solution into my system. However, when I tried it on my code, it did not work.

Here's the flow:
If `DEPARTMENT` is equals to `Grade School` then `Grade & Section`, dropdown will only show the `Kindergarten` to `Grade 6` and then if `DEPARTMENT` is equals to `Junior High School`, dropdown will only shows `Grade 7` to `Grade 10` while if `DEPARTMENT` is equals to `Senior High School`, dropdown will only shows `Grade 11` to `Grade 12`.

User interface:
[image]

Here's the code that I'm using..

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
    <label for="first-name-icon">Department</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <div class="input-group mb-3" id="dept">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
        <select class="form-select category" id="dept" name="dept" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="GS">Grade School</option>
          <option value="JHS">Junior High School</option>
          <option value="SHS">Senior High School</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
    <label for="first-name-icon">Grade & Section (for students only)</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
        <select class="form-select operator" id="u_grdsec" name="u_grdsec">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="Grade 1" class="GS">Grade 1</option>
          <option value="Grade 2" class="GS">Grade 2</option>
          <option value="Grade 7" class="JHS">Grade 7</option>
          <option value="Grade 8" class="JHS">Grade 8</option>
          <option value="Grade 11" class="SHS">Grade 11</option>
          <option value="Grade 12" class="SHS">Grade 12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('change', '.category', function () {
          var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $('.operator option').hide();
          $('.operator option.'+val).show();
          $('.operator option.'+val+':first').attr('selected','selected').change();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the screenshot of my database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A quick fix to a minor problem**

The problem is a very minor one that is difficult to spot, but very easily fixed.

The department field values in your database are uppercase, but the script tries to match to lowercase. So there is never a match and script hides all of your grade options.

To fix this problem, change the following line of code as shown:

```
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); // incorrect
```

change that to:

```
var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase(); // correct
```

Yes, it is that simple!  You were very close, but just needed a little help spotting the bug. ;)

You can run the snippet below to see your code working.

**Addendum:**
There's one other (optional) change you might want to make. Append a "removeAttr" to the following line. This will clear the previous selection when a different department is selected.

```
 $('.operator option').hide().removeAttr("selected");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('change', '.category', function () {
          // var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();  // <----- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
          var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
          $('.operator option').hide().removeAttr("selected");
          $('.operator option.'+val).show();
          $('.operator option.'+val+':first').attr('selected','selected').change();
      });
  });
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
    <label for="first-name-icon">Department</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <div class="input-group mb-3" id="dept">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
        <select class="form-select category" id="dept" name="dept" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="GS">Grade School</option>
          <option value="JHS">Junior High School</option>
          <option value="SHS">Senior High School</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
    <label for="first-name-icon">Grade & Section (for students only)</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
        <select class="form-select operator" id="u_grdsec" name="u_grdsec">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
          <option class="GS">Kindergarten</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 1</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 2</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 3</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 4</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 5</option>
          <option class="GS">Grade 6</option>
          <option class="JHS">Grade 7</option>
          <option class="JHS">Grade 8</option>
          <option class="JHS">Grade 9</option>
          <option class="JHS">Grade 10</option>
          <option class="SHS">Grade 11</option>
          <option class="SHS">Grade 12</option>
       
<!--  PHP and DB disabled for this example

          <?php
            $conn = OpenCon();
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `grdlvl`";
            
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
            ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['g_grdsec']; ?>" class="<?php echo $row['g_dept']; ?>"><?php echo $row['g_grdsec']; ?></option>
          <?php
            }
            }
            ?>
-->            
            
            
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @cjwrk - Thanks for the points.  I just added an addendum to the end of the answer with an optional change you might also consider.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the previous question you had and decided to simply use the example that was created in that question - but inside a codepen that works.
https://codepen.io/Stoffe91/pen/YzYpwNO

HTML below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<select class="category">
    <option val="price">Price</option>
    <option val="weight">weight</option>
    <option val="size">Size</option>
    <option val="dimension">Dimension</option>
</select>
<select class="operator">
    <option val="1" class="price">For Price 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="price">For Price 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="price">For Price 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="price">For Price 4</option>    
    <option val="1" class="weight">For Weight 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="weight">For Weight 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="weight">For Weight 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="weight">For Weight 4</option>    
    <option val="1" class="size">For Size 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="size">For Size 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="size">For Size 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="size">For Size 4</option>
    <option val="1" class="dimension">For Dimension 1</option>
    <option val="2" class="dimension">For Dimension 2</option>
    <option val="3" class="dimension">For Dimension 3</option>
    <option val="4" class="dimension">For Dimension 4</option>
</select>
```

Jquery below:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.category', function () {
      console.log('now');
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.operator option').hide();
        $('.operator option.'+val).show();
       $('.operator option.'+val+':first').attr('selected','selected').change();
    });
});
```

Check this one out.
If you're having issues with it, please specify what part of it you're having issues with. Simply apply this on your current project.

Comment: It still doesn't work on my code and if I add this line `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`, the Grade & Section downdrop option doesn't show any data. However, if I removed it, it shows all the data of Grade & Section on my DB. Can you apply the solution using my code?

Comment: The problem at that point is that you don't understand the code you're trying to write. I recommend dumbing your code down a bit. Remove your db connection and simply adjust it to follow this kind of logic - then you add the other stuff. Not the other way around.

Comment: I already updated the codes.